# How does the ? make a quantifier lazy in regex

Tags: operators, regular-expressions

I've been looking into regex lately and figured that the `?` operator makes the `*`,`+`, or `?` lazy. My question is how does it do that?

Is it that `*?` for example is a special operator, or does the `?` have an effect on the `*`? In other words, does regex recognize `*?` as one operator in itself, or does regex recognize `*?` as the two separate operators `*` and `?`?

If it is the case that `*?` is being recognized as two separate operators, how does the `?` affect the `*` to make it lazy. If `?` means that the `*` is optional, shouldn't this mean that the `*` doesn't have to exists at all. If so, then in a statement `.*?` wouldn't regex just match separate letters and the whole string instead of the shorter string?

Please explain, I'm desperate to understand.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters In the practice of programming, no, but in being knowledgeable in programming, yes.

Comment: They are two separate operators, and the `?` has 2 meanings, depending on its context, same as with `^` that may mean `beginning-of-line` or negation if it is the first char inside a `[]` pair.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `*?` is definitely one operator and not the normal `*` with a modifying meta-operator. It is commonly named similar to `*` for mnemonic purposes only.

The effect that `*?` has in contrast to `*` is subtle, but it goes deep enough into the expression engine that it has to be treated in a different way at the "transmission" level (deciding whether to backtrack or not), and that can't be done by something applied to the result of a normal `*`. (For much, much more information, read chapter 4 of [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596528124).)